# How many groups of 8 numbers can be formed from 45 lottery numbers, except a few rules.

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, lotteries

I'm trying to figure out how many groups of 8 lottery numbers can be formed from the set $A=\{1,2,3,\dotsc,45\}$. The first 3 numbers are "winning" numbers and the left over 5 "losing" numbers.

I understand that I need to figure out how many groups of 8 can be formed from 45 elements.

$$\binom{45}8 = \frac{45!}{8!(45-8)!}.$$

What I'm having a problem with is understanding how to take these rules into account.

Maybe something like:

$$\binom{45}3 * \binom{42}5?$$

To be honest I'm quite lost. All hints and pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Why "Maybe something like..."?  What gives rise to your lack of confidence?  Why do you think that this might be correct?  or incorrect?

Comment: Also relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3291362/ , https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2620057/468350 . These questions ask about probabilities, but there is a connection (look at the numerators).

Comment: It was a hunch based on some other combinatorics I have done, calculating password combinations with similar restrictions. But thanks to the material you linked, I got it and understood how it works.